# How to view local images through WebViewer in App Inventor 2?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I need to install images with the application. Images should be inside the application.
I want to use WebViewer because the images should be scalable.

Comment: Do the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to ask questions here at stackoverflow. Also do the [tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor. Then try something and in case there are still problems, show us what you have tried...

Answer (score 1):

See this snippet: https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2ani

**You can access images directly with the webviewer component.**

There is one special thing to consider for HTML documents uploaded as assets into App Inventor: During development, you have to use the development path to the embedded HTML document.

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/AppInventor/assets/ani.gif
```

Before building the app, use the production path.

```
file:///android_asset/ani.gif
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

First I uploaded in assets the image omrosu_ridica_omalbastru.png

Then I changed an example you provided at **webviewstring2**

as follows

`<h1>How to display some HTML text in a webviewer</h1> <h2>during runtime of your app</h2> <p>Just put your string together and pass it to the Webviewer using the <b>webviewstring</b> property.<br><br> <img src="file:///android_asset/omrosu_ridica_omalbastru.png" alt="PuraVidaApps" style="border:0;width:200px;height:187px;"></p><p><a href="https://puravidaapps.com">More great tricks you can find at puravidaapps.com</a>. Woo Hoo!</p>`

It worked to display the image both for

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/omrosu_ridica_omalbastru.png" ...
```

and

```
<img src="omrosu_ridica_omalbastru.png" ...
```

Regards,

Mihai